# Preview Support Library Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

Here's the error i'm getting everytime i actually use CardView or Recyclerview in my app

> Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

What can we do to use it on Eclipse?

> How can we add the preview support library?

Comment: did you import the preview support library?

Comment: the same way you do any other library project

Comment: where is it found ? in what directory?

Comment: @tyczj in what folder is it found in sdk folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Support Repository - Revision 6 in Android SDK manager has the necessary classes for CardView and RecyclerView.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "Android Support Repository"? what's the difference between it and the normal support library? is it like a beta of the support library?